# How to disable the restart confirmation prompt after doing updates with Discover?

Tags: updates, kde, session

Ubuntu Studio 23.04, Kde Plasma 5.27.4 :

after I do updates with Discover, a button appears telling me to reboot: if I click it, a confirmation window appears, with a 30-second countdown: I would like the system to reboot immediately when I click "reboot" on Discover. Granted that I have already disabled from the settings "session close screen" (unchecked "show") and that this happens to me only after doing updates: if instead I click on "restart" or "shut down" or something else from the application menu, the 'action is performed directly, without prompt/confirmation window, as I wanted.
How can I solve this?

Thank you.
Montyzoom.